# Connect Active X Combobox to Pivot Table Filter

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am having some problems in linking an Active X combobox to a Pivot table filter. Basically I will need to have the users to select from the combobox an ID that needs to be linked to the Pivot table filter.  I am using the following code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim ptField As PivotField
Set sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Overview")
Set pt = sheet.PivotTables("Main")
Set ptField = pt.PivotFields("CustomersId")
ptField.ClearAllFilters
ptField.CurrentPage = Me.ComboBox1.Value
End Sub
```

The error I get is: "Unable to get the PivotFields property of the PivotTable Class".

Any idea of what is wrong with the above code? Something that I m missing?

Thank you in advance

Comment: It could be "CustomerId" rather than "CustomersId" or something else but definitely that field doesn't exist in pivot table and hence the error.